# Can i give google indexing to my android app but i don't have a website

Tags: android

Please some on guide me the way to give Google indexing to my android app but i don't have a website on my own. All i want is to show my app on searching in Google and on clicking that search item it should go to play store.

Here is the google developer doc for the same. 
https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/?hl=en
Please someone could help me explain how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Google indexes websites. If you have a unique app or other way for Google to recognize your app among many others, then submit your app to other app "markets" like Amazon or AppBrain.

You can also submit to websites that review apps or want to reference to talk about "new" or interesting apps.

You can also pay people to write or blog about your app, but that is a possible violation of the Google Play Store TOS (subject to interpretation of course).

Comment: I'm need help on how to do indexing on Google searches. Kindly provide anything helpful on that topic. Here is the documentation provided by Google for that. But i'm not able to understand it properly. https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/

Comment: Google looks for references to your content (or app) on many websites. The more websites that have links or content related to your app, the more likely your app is to be ranked higher on search. "indexing" is another word for "finding you on websites"

Comment: Thanks for giving knowledge on this topic. but i need a solution for the question.

Comment: Google indexes websites - the only solution is to have your app mentioned in websites. What more do you want for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

App indexing allows developers to connect pages from your app web site with specific content within your Android app. This enables Android smartphone users who have your app installed to open it directly from relevant mobile search results on Google. If you don't have a website connected to your app I don't think you can index your app for **Google Search Results**.

Having said that you could try to add app indexing to your app only for **Google Search App** just to re-engage the user but I'm no sure if it is possible to do that or not.